# Cloud firestore trigger query by documentID for array of ids

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a transaction that first query documents by documentId from a list of ids, then makes some updates.

I am getting the error:

> The corresponding value for FieldPath.documentId() must be a string or a DocumentReference.

For example:

```
const indexArray = [..list of doc ids...]
const personQueryRef = db.collection("person").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", indexArray)

return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
  return transaction.get(personQueryRef).then(personQuery => {
    return personQuery.forEach(personRef => {
      transaction.update(personRef, { ...update values here })
      //more updates etc
    })
  })
})
```

I am wanting to do this in an `onCreate` and `onUpdate` trigger. Is there another approach I should be taking?

**Update**

The error still persists when not using a transaction, so this is unrelated to the problem.

The problem does not occur when the query is `.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", "just_one_doc_id")`. So, the problem is with using `FieldPath.documentId()` and `in`.

Comment: I'm certain this doesn't have anything to do with Cloud Functions or the type of trigger you're using.  Are you certain this has to do with the transaction?  What if you just execute the `personQueryRef` query without the transaction?

Comment: Also I suggest you take that error message an paste it into a web search - there are lot of other questions that report the same thing.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have simplified my function to not use a transaction and it still errors in the same way. The error does not occur when I do `admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", "just_one_doc_id"`. Is there another way to achieve this for an array of ids? Other stack overflow/results don't seem to answer this very well.

Comment: I could do multiple queries and join the results - is this a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the type of query you're trying to do just isn't supported by the SDK.  Whether or not that's intentional, I don't know.  But if you want to transact with multiple documents, and you already know all of their IDs, you can use [getAll(...)](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#getAll) instead:

```
// build an array of DocumentReference objects
cost refs = indexArray.map(id => db.collection("person").doc(id))

return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
  // pass the array to getAll()
  return transaction.getAll(refs).then(docs => {
    docs.forEach(doc => {
      transaction.update(doc.ref, { ...update values here })
    })
  })
})
```